# Set javascript ScrollTo after submit form with updatepanel and masterpages

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, updatepanel

I have a form with a submit function in a updatepanel.

To test it I use alert and this is working fine. I submit the form and the alert pops up. So the code is working.

```
protected void SendProfileForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), 
    "ScrollTo", "alert('test');", true);
}
```

Now I change it into this, and this does nothing.

```
protected void SendProfileForm_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), 
    "ScrollTo", "window.scrollTo(0, 500);", true);
}
```

if I do a onclientclick with this code window.scrollTo(0, 500); then it is working. So this javascript code is working.

What am I doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are posting a asynchronous call you must use `ScriptManager` client API:

```
Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_pageLoaded(MyScrollTo);
```

This will fire that `function` every time the page load. So you need to code some logic to this work:

```
var needScroll;

function MyScrollTo(){
     if(needScroll){
        window.scrollTo(0,500);
     }
}
```

So you server side code need to set `needScroll` variable:

```
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this.Page, this.Page.GetType(), 
    "ScrollTo", "var needScroll = true;", true);
```

If you want more information about `ScriptManager` client API take a look [here](http://www.asp.net/ajax/documentation/live/ClientReference/Sys.WebForms/default.aspx).

Comment: do you have a example? I looked into it but I can't get it to work. I must call the script dynamically from the code behind because I want to scroll to different section on the page. Thanks.

Comment: I elaborated my answer. Can you try again? If it works at first time try again. Sometimes `ScriptManager` don't like you using javascript directly.